# How to refresh data inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

From `viewController1` the `didSelectRow` takes the user to `viewController2`. Upon selecting a value there, that value is carried back and should be displayed in `viewController1`. The data is being passed fine. I'm adding a logic to check if data was received inside `cellForRow` of `viewController1`. Still the old data is shown. How do I refresh the data for that cell only and not via `tableView.reloadData()`?

That indexPath.row needs to deque a different type of cell if data was successfully received from `viewController2`

Answer (score 2):

Use **reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)** with specified index path for row that needs to be updated.

Comment: Thank you. How can value be supplied for that particular row? It needs to sequence a different type of cell as well.

Comment: You should have some sort of model from where rows are configured. Updating row(s) will call "cellForRow" and there should be all the logic to set values from the model or get different cells. So don't forget to save model with the new values.

Comment: Thank you. I updated this info in the question too: how to deque a different type of cell when back to `viewController1`?

Comment: Edit your question to show your `cellForRow(at:)` code; as @kirander said, the logic should be in that method to dequeue the right cell type based on your data

Answer (score 1):

I've met a similar case, my solution is add a property to record the index path which the user clicked.
And refresh this index path in view will appear

```
var leaveAtIndexPath: IndexPath?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    leaveAtIndexPath = indexPath
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if leaveAtIndexPath != nil {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [leaveAtIndexPath], with: .none)
        leaveAtIndexPath = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

to reload the row, and then in your **cellForRowAt**, you can use a flag to see whether the user has selected the cell or whether the data has changed.

```
var userHasSelected[IndexPath:Bool] = [:] // populate this with your cell data 
if userHasSelected[indexpath] {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userSelected", for: indexPath)
else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userNotSelected", for: indexPath)
}
```

This is what I would do.